# Users can post new node but ONLY Unpublished status

Tags: 8, theming, users

As the title says, users are able to create new node (type QUESTION), but they can not publish it. The node is saved when the user hits save, but the status is set to unpublished under Admin > Content. 
I have checked a few permissions the authenticated user which has:

- Question: Create new content
- Question: Edit own content
- View published content
- View own unpublished content

This content is NOT using workflow moderation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious thing is that the "published" option is unticked on the content type. So if you go to "structure > content types > question" (/admin/structure/types/manage/question) and then click "Publishing option" is the published ticked? That controls the default status

If its not that then you must have some other module/code doing it. Without knowing your sites setup I dont think people can help much further

Comment: Leigh...thanks for the quick reply. That was it. Now I am laughing at myself.